# Hash of byte array in Java

Tags: java, c#, hash

I'm converting some C# to Java. The C# is:

```
// Return a SHA256 hash of a string, formatted in hex
private static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] utf8 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    return BytesToHex(hash.ComputeHash(utf8));
}
```

In Java I replaced `SHA256Managed` with `MessageDigest`:

```
private static String HashPassword(String password)
{
    MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] utf8 = hash.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    return BytesToHex(hash.ComputeHash(utf8)); // ComputeHash?
}
```

but `MessageDigest` does not have `ComputeHash()` nor do I see its equivalent.
Is `MessageDigest` the correct class to use here? If so, what do I do for `ComputeHash()`. If not what class do I use?

Note that `BytesToHex` Converts a byte array to a hex string.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for `MessageDigest`? The method to finalize the hash is `digest()` for a hash calculated in several segments, or `digest(byte[])` for a single-segment calculation (or as the final segment of a multi-segment hash).

Comment: I did read, but not carefully. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MessageDigest` is stateful. You pass data to it incrementally, and call `digest()` to compute the hash over all the data when you're done.

The `hash.digest(byte[])` method you're calling is essentially a shorthand for `hash.update(byte[])` then `hash.digest()`.

Calling `digest()` also resets the `MessageDigest` instance to its initial state.

Answer (score 2):

In your Java, the variable `utf8` contains your computed hash unlike the C#. To match the way the C# looks it should be:

```
byte[] utf8 = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

return bytesToHex(hash.digest(utf8));
```

Side note: Please respect Java coding standards with respect to `lowerCamelCased` method names.